# display:table-cell not working on an input element

Tags: css

I want to do a portion of a form look like a spreadsheet.
There are several forms and `<table>` is thus not viable (though I'm not against it when you do are printing semantically tabular data, as it is the case).

So I tried to simply use a CSS2.1 layout directly with the form input elements, eg.

```
<div class="table">
    <form class="tbody">
        <div class="tr">
            <label class="td">Label</label>
            <input class="td" name />
            <input class="td" name />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Full example in **[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyhJw/1/)**.

But it looks like **`display:table-cell` does not work on `<input>` elements**!

If you check in Chrome "Computed Style" the display will be "inline-element".

But I did not find anywhere why it shouldn't:

- [Mozilla Dev Network CSS:display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display)
- [W3C CSS 2.1 Recommendation Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display)
- [W3C Tables Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#value-def-table-cell)

Any idea?

It sounded so much better than having some `<div class="cell">` around the `<input>` and then having to play with box-model to get it look nice...

Comment: If so, that's no shock. Relatively little styling is possible on HTML form elements. They're rendered more by the native operating system than by the browser. Trying to apply `display:table-cell` to an HTML form element sounds a bit extreme, under the circumstances.

Comment: unfortunately the issue is not much with the rendering but with the visual formatting model. I can easily style my input as I want... but I can't get it behave as a CELL!

Comment: sorry for causing more confusion or just wasting your time. computed style in firefox is display:table-cell...maybe chrome or webkit bug?

Comment: @albert Yes in Firefox computed style is correct... but behaviour still isnt :D So I guess internally it behaves the same. In mozilla there's an outstanding bug exactly on this subject: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=281357  And no problem, thanks for trying to help!!!

Comment: lol. more like not helping....sorry again @stefano

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html):

> "CSS 2.1 does not define which properties apply to form controls and frames, or how CSS can be used to style them. User agents may apply CSS properties to these elements. Authors are recommended to treat such support as experimental. A future level of CSS may specify this further."

Sorry, but `display: table-cell` on `input` elements is treated experimental. Try to avoid it, use wrapper-elements for the positioning for example.

I've made an example with `div` elements. You can now have multiple forms within a table, however it only works when the `form` element spans full rows. Otherwise your nesting will be broken.

**EDIT:**
Updated the fiddle with a version where `border-collapse` is added to avoid double borders.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/beacj/2/)

Comment: thanks Justus, yes I agree I can wrap them. It just makes it so more complex css-wise to avoid those double lines you have in your fiddle (use only bottom-right borders + top and left on first ones only). I also agree that my forms have to span full rows, I use a trick with input names to make it a bit more flexible...

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse` only works on native tables, so yeah you have to jiggle with classnames to get rid of the double borders.

Comment: Actually, that DOES work. I'll update the fiddle and link. I had the border on the input elements, but if you put the border on the `div` nodes that display as cells, the border collapses appropriatly!