# Span, Input, Span 100% width CSS issue

Tags: html, css, less

This is what i'm doing right now. I'm using LESS CSS for my design. I need to put 2 spans between a specified input. all the elements should be 100% width. spans should always 20px width input width can be change according to the screen width. Can anyone help me?

span width: 20px;

[image: How I need]

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <span class="span-one">span</span>
 <input type="text" class="input">
 <span class="span-two">span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What CSS do you currently have?

Comment: It seems like the difficulty with this is resizing the `input`. You can’t give the `input` `width: 100%` because it needs to leave room for two 20px spans. And if you give it `width: auto`, it doesn’t take up the remaining space, it just takes up the browser default width for an `input`.

Comment: Here’s [a jsFiddle for everyone to use as a starting point](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/DZBBk/)

Comment: There are many solutions. Here's one: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/DZBBk/4/

Comment: what are you using the 20px spans for?  if you are trying to add a margin then you should just set the left and right margins of the input to 20px

Comment: @Malachi: Presumably, something will go inside the `span`s.

Comment: if it is a just for background then there would be no need to set two spans for this, that is why I am asking what it is going to be used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with absolute positioning. It will take the spans out of the flow and put them on top of the input. You should also put the input in a div to do this as it doesn't naturally get 100% width when display:block set on it.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <span class="span-one">span</span>
 <div class="input"><input type="text" class="input"></div>
 <span class="span-two">span</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper { position: relative; }

div.input { margin: 0 20px; }

input { 
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }

span.span-one {
  position: absolute;
  width:20px; height:20px;
  left:0; top:0;
  background-color: red; }

span.span-two {
  position: absolute;
  width:20px; height:20px;
  right:0; top:0;
  background-color: red; }
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ywUeu/1/

Of course the word 'span' in the spans is longer than 20px so it comes out of the span.
Might be best to add 'box-sizing' to input as I've done too.

Comment: Nope. I tried. Last span going down. and there are little spaces between span and input when we do like this. Try adding backgroud colors to your code. Then you can see the issue.

Comment: @MinuwanDeshapriya not sure what you mean. Please see the fiddle, I've done it with background colors instead. Seems to work fine to me?

Comment: Sorry just added new fiddle link. Realised the old link was still on there.

Comment: Yes, I made few changes(height, padding, margin) and now looks great. Thanks @Coop :)

Answer (score 1):

**Positioning is not ideal** but you already approved the answer...this is an FYI....

Instead of positioning use: `display: table-cell;`

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/CBC5A/1/

Comment: `display: table-cell` on `input` elements can be dodgy, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element. I haven't actually tried it for a while though, but to be safe I included a wrapper element in the jsFiddle in my comment on the question.

Comment: I have check latest Chrome-FF-IE -Safari and nothing seems to be off

Comment: Try removing `input { display: table-cell; }`. Nothing changes. It's *somehow* `width: inherit` which is giving the `input` the correct width.

Comment: even better that way :)

Comment: Well, that's one way of looking at it. I don't understand why or how it works. It doesn't seem robust.

Answer (score 0):

With your HTML:

```
.wrapper, .text {
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
}
.wrapper.input {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Better way:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="input"><input type="text" class="text-input"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*
.wrapper, .input{ width is 100% by default }
*/
.text-input{
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Comment: Warning: `calc` [is not supported in IE8 and below](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). And `calc` noticeably slows down style recalculation upon window resize on my machine.