# Display: table-cell problems in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have 3 divs that I would like to display as table cells:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="name">Subdomain</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        <div class="subdomain-base ">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS that I am using:

```
body{
    font-size: 13px;
}

.field {
    width:450px;
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.row > * {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
label {
    width: 125px;
    height: 18px;
}
input {
    max-width: none;
    min-width: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}
.subdomain-base {
    height: 18px;
    width: 1px;
}
.subdomain-base {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

It works perfectly in Firefox 24:
[image]

However, it has a height problem in Chrome 30 (latest):
[image]

I have been trying all sorts of things to fix the problem with Chrome, but it seems like nothing works. Why is chrome getting that extra height?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahLMH/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be due to `display: table-cell` on `input` elements being experimental. See this question for more details: [display:table-cell not working on an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element)

The solution is to wrap the input in a `span` and apply `display: table-cell` to the `span` and to remove `overflow: auto` from the `input`.

The new mark up looks like so:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Subdomain</label>
    <span>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    </span>

    <div class="subdomain-base ">test</div>
</div>
```

The css now looks like this:

```
body {
    font-size: 13px;
}
.field {
    width:450px;
    display: table;
}
.field > * {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
span {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
label {
    width: 125px;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
}
.subdomain-base {
    width: 1px;
}
.subdomain-base {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahLMH/6/

Answer (score 3):

Set this:

```
.row > * {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top; // add this
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ahLMH/2/)

Comment: Problem is that now the text is aligned to the top (where as I would like it to be aligned to the baseline).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, don't have enough rep to respond to Dhaval's answer.

Change to

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahLMH/3/

Comment: User want in baseline