# Div content in wrong position

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put 3 divs in the same row as the following code.

My CSS and HTML:

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}
.row > div {

  display: table-cell;
  height:30px; /*demo purposes */
}
#left-bar {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#middle-bar {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #6600FF;
}
#right-bar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #99FF99;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="left-bar"> here I have an accordion </div>
  <div id="middle-bar"> heve a have my canvas </div>
  <div id="right-bar"> and here I have an editor</div>
</div>
```

Somehow the content of the middle-bar(my canvas) is positioned in the correct place, but the other two divs contents are in the bottom of the page as you can see here [see photo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65983811/Screenshot%20from%202015-06-10%2001%3A23%3A56.png). Do you guys know why this is happening?

Comment: Which browser/version are you testing in? (Your photo link is broken)

Comment: can you post fiddle because the link to photo is not working?

Comment: I will upload the photo to dropbox. Its because I posted It im my gmail account

Comment: Seems to work as-is in Chrome 43. Does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/mtq8zjgv/1/?

Comment: Guys, I uploaded the photo to my dropbox, see if this works now

Comment: You can checkout out this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614408/display-table-cell-problems-in-chrome

Comment: Yes, Jonathan, this fiddle works normal!

Comment: I think check elements that teke them in these 3 "div"s.

Comment: Jonathan you are right. I have tested with chrome 43. Its working fine.

I think this is due to default padding and margin added browsers to the element.  @Rafael can you set margin:0px; padding:0px; outline:0px; to .row class and same for .row>div .

Comment: @Dinesh, added the lines you mentioned, unfortunately It is still happening. I think that is something wrong with my code inside the divs......or maybe some css I added to classes that represent these elements inside the divs

Comment: @Rafael I'm happy to hear the fiddle works; I've moved the suggestion into an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing the project further with you in the comments, and in chat, I think you should take an approach that uses [*flexbox*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) instead. The code is fairly straight forward:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.left   { flex-basis: 10%; background: #F99; }
.right  { flex-basis: 20%; background: #99F; }
.middle { flex-basis: 70%; background: #9F9; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="middle">C</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, Jonathan unfortunately It still happening....I think I broke the matrix, just kidding, I'm doing something wrong in my code but I have no idea where It is. I tryied removing the canvas and the other two divs behaved correctly, so I think the error is something with my canvas, but I'm not sure

Comment: What if you added `.table, .table * { box-sizing: border-box }` to the solution?

Comment: Add this and the other things you mentioned? I will try here

Comment: Same thing is happening.

Comment: @Rafael Can you please update the fiddle to better reflect your code? Also, what is your baseline as far as browser support is concerned?

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I don't care if I don't work in every browser, if this work in chrome It is fine :) (this is my graduation project and my teacher only uses chrome) I discoved that if I change the canvas heigth the other divs go up, let me update the fiddle

Comment: @Rafael We could use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) instead, which is supported in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer 10 and 11 (I work on the Internet Explorer team). It will work far better, since it was designed for this very purpose.

Comment: is flexbox free license? If yes I'll use It

Comment: Flexbox is a web standard, so it requires no licensing to use. It is natively supported in modern browsers (like `display: table`), and is quick to get setup. I'll build a quick demo for you in just a moment.

Comment: Jonathan, someone suggested adding: "vertical-align: middle;", I changed to vertical-align: top; and It apparently worked oO, do you thing this is elegant or is a jerry-rigged (I don't know if this is the correct expression in english).

Comment: No, forget everything I said, It is A BIG jerry-rigged ...It is not working....I will study the flexbox

Comment: @Rafael I am not personally a fan of `display: table` solutions. I *feel* as though they are often inherently "jerry-rigged," so I would prefer flexbox here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtq8zjgv/2/

Comment: Hey Jonathan, It worked partially, the divs are now on the top, but the proportions are incorrect :S....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80126/discussion-between-jonathan-sampson-and-rafael).

Comment: Hey Jonathan, sorry for the later response I woke up and went to university, and only arrived home now. I would like to thank you again, YOU ROCK!

Answer (score 0):

I only managed width.
There's nothing problematic see this.

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}
.row > div {

  display: table-cell;
  height:30px; /*demo purposes */
}
#left-bar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#middle-bar {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #6600FF;
}
#right-bar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #99FF99;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="left-bar"> here I have an accordion </div>
  <div id="middle-bar"> heve a have my canvas </div>
  <div id="right-bar"> and here I have an editor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, Dimple, unfortunately the same thing is happenig.

Comment: Tryied to add the "float:left" inside each div, now everything is weird (out of position). Man I have no ideia why this is happennig

Comment: Can u send me your html file?