# display: table-cell breaks tabs in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Building a set of tabs. I'd like them to be equal widths based on number of tabs. Minimum number is 2, maximum number is 5.

Did the CSS thing where:

```
.tabs__header {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabs__button {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Works fine in IE and Firefox. When I test it in Chrome, it goes nuts and sets the .tabs__button to 100% width.

[image: What happens when I hover over my tabs in Chrome]

If I change the CSS to:

```
.tabs__button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then it works fine, but I lose the ability set tabs to equal widths.

Is there a workaround or fix for this?

Comment: this could be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614408/display-table-cell-problems-in-chrome

Comment: Can you make a snippet?