# vertically align an input using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to vertically align an input in my project. My code works for a span but don't work for input! whats the reason?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8ESb/546/)

CSS code:

```
.float  {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  display: table;
  border: solid 1px blue;  
  height: 120px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div  class="col-sm-12 ">    
    <span class='float'>Float right</span>
</div>
<div  class="col-sm-12 ">     
    <input class='float' id='btnReport' name='btnReport'   type='button' value='report' />     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code should be

> `<div class="float">
>   <input id='btnReport' name='btnReport' type='button' value='report' />   </div>`

you can check below link for demo

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/e8ESb/552/)

Answer (score 1):

As answered in this question:

[display:table-cell not working on an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element#15632230)

> "CSS 2.1 does not define which properties apply to form controls and
>   frames, or how CSS can be used to style them. User agents may apply
>   CSS properties to these elements. Authors are recommended to treat
>   such support as experimental. A future level of CSS may specify this
>   further."

A possible workaround might be to wrap the input in a div with the float class:

```
<div  class="col-sm-12 ">     
             <div class="float"><input id='btnReport' name='btnReport' type='button' value='report' />   
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think verticle-align property applied to content inside the element, and input element doesnt have any. You can wrap input element with dev tag and apply float class to it