# CSS “display: table-cell” for columns - Make the width of first column the same as the widest word

Tags: html, css, tablecell

I have several different forms which are styled using display: table-cell such as seen in this one example of one form in this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/leopardy/ysyf33mq/

I would like for the first column, the one that is acting as labels,  to be the width of the longest text which in this case is the text Confirm Password. Therefore all the 'boxes' with the label text Username, Email, Company and Password should be the same width as Confirm Password box.

All of this text should pretty much be static, so it is sufficient if I can set the column to a specific width and manually change it later if the text changes. However, it would be even better if the width would self adjust so that if I changed the text in the future, the width of all the items in the first column would adjust automatically. I have tried so many things I can't even remember them all, however I did leave one commented out styling in the CSS to give an idea of what I have tried.

HTML:

```
<div class="entry-group">
    <span class="label-group">Username</span>
    <input id="new_username" type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="entry-group">
    <span class="label-group">Email</span>
    <input id="email_address" type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="entry-group">
    <span class="label-group">Company</span>
    <input id="company" type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="entry-group">
    <span class="label-group">Password</span>
    <input id="new_password" type="password" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="entry-group">
    <span class="label-group">Confirm Password</span>
    <input id="confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div id="terms">
    <label><input id="terms_checkbox" type="checkbox" />I agree to the <a href="something.html" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a></label>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.entry-group {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.entry-group .form-control {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.label-group,
.entry-group .form-control {
  display: table-cell;
}

.label-group {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* .label-group.col {
    width: 20px;
} */

.form-control {
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/egL3py32/). Your table structure is almost complete, so here are a few minor adjustments to create the needed table rows. There is a new wrapper div called .table-style with `display:table`. Since you already have the table structure, I used `display:table-row` on .entry-group. `Display:table-cell` is still used on .label-group and .form-control.

```
.table-style {
    display:table;
}

.entry-group {
  display:table-row;
}


.label-group, .form-control {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Note: If you have issues with table-cell on an input tag, you may want to read this [Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element)

Comment: Excellent. Any idea on how to add spacing in between each table-row now?

Comment: Use border-spacing: 3px; on the .table-style. It works along with     border-collapse: separate;. I updated the JSFiddle.