# input/button display:table-cell/width:100% do not fill remaining space in table

Tags: html, css, button, input

I'm styling an input group `<div>` wrapper as `display:table;` with all contents `display:table-cell;` When I want to have a fixed width on the table, if the cell I want to widen/shorten to take up the remainder width is a `<span>` element or a `<ul>` element, for example, then setting `width:100%;` works. However, if the element is an `<input>` or `<button>` then this does not work in firefox or chrome (but does in IE) and the result is the element takes up the entire space of the input group, pushing the next element down to a new row. I can get around this by putting the `<input>` or `<button>` inside a `<span>` element and setting `width:100%;` on both, but I'd rather have a css solution.

```
<div class="input-group wide">
    <input  type="text" style="width:100%;"></input>
    <button>S</button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.input-group {
    display:inline-table;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.input-group > input, .input-group > button, .input-group > span, .input-group > ul {
    display: table-cell;
    margin:0px;
}
.wide {
    width: 260px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5v3Lg50d/3/

Comment: I think you're limited to using a wrapper (such as a span).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats are good idea, you can follow Epik's solution.
I checked one thing with Firebug for Firefox and I learned that `<button>` works fine with its parent `div` having `style="display: inline-flex"`.
You might want to check this against other browsers and use it conditionally, or go with floats instead.

Comment: Thanks for that: I just changed to display:inline-flex; in the input-group class, and display: inline-block; for the inner elements and it is now all sweet-as: http://jsfiddle.net/5v3Lg50d/6/

Answer (score 1):

I have a JS fiddle here with the changes made.
http://jsfiddle.net/5v3Lg50d/4/

Basically i changed a few small things and tidied up your fiddle. The elements you wanted full width i added in a class and floated left;

```
.fullWidth {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

The following is the code i amended:

```
<div class="input-group wide" style="">
    <span class="fullWidth">space</span>
    <button>S</button>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="input-group wide" style="">
    <ul class="fullWidth"><li>o1</li><li>o2</li></ul>
    <button>S</button>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="input-group wide" style="">
    <input  type="text" class="fullWidth"></input>
    <button>S</button>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="input-group wide">
    <span><input class="fullWidth"></input></span>
    <button class="fullWidth">S</button>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="input-group wide">
    <button class="fullWidth">A button</button>
    <button>S</button>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="input-group wide" style="">
    <span><button  class="fullWidth">A button</button></span>
    <button>S</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.
-Epik

Comment: That is now filling the entire width of the table, not the *remaining* width. i.e. the button to the right should still appear on the same row as the <input> and first <button>. The fiddle in the OP shows this working fine for <span>'s and <ul>'s in the outer <div> but not for <input>'s and <button>'s