# CSS, two columns - left with dynamic width (input), right with fixed (button)

Tags: html, css

can somebody please point me to a solution for this?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="left" />
    <button class="right">Some button</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.left, .right {
   display: table-cell;
}

.right { width: 100px; }
```

Here is code pen sample: http://codepen.io/be-codified/pen/qdRRBY

Input field should be stretchable, button should be fixed positioned on right.

Thank you in advance.

// edit

I can not use table tag because layout needs to be responsive.

Comment: I think you're looking to use a textarea, not an input.

Comment: It needs to be an input.

Comment: may I ask why? a textarea is a **resizable input** for text. You can even stop it being resized vertically by using `max-height` and `height` properties. [demo with textarea](http://jsfiddle.net/cs5x03aq/)

Comment: Textarea is a multiple rows input.

Comment: Maybe I am not getting what you want. Do you (a) want your div to be resizable via drag/drop or (b) resizable in terms of screen size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave the `input` a width of `calc(100% - 110px)` and the button a `float:right` which resulted in [the following](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVxWYw). Is that what you need? The input type you want to use is, as far as I know, not stretchable by the user.

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.left, .right {
  display: table-cell;
}

.right { 
  width: 100px; 
  float: right;
}

input.left {
  width: calc(100% - 110px); //This makes sure the input area is as wide as possible, while also leaving space for the button. Play with the exact measurements to get what you need.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to put the form elements into `<div>`, so don't change their default display properties, and then set the left input box to 100% width as needed.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.left, .right {
  display: table-cell;
}
.right {
  width: 100px;
}
.left input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"><input type="text" /></div>
  <div class="right"><button>Some button</button></div>
</div>
```

In fact, both left and right can have dynamic width, so right column always get the minimum width based on the button length.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.left, .right {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.left {
  width: 100%;
}
.left input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"><input type="text" /></div>
  <div class="right"><button>Some button</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Zigson read this [display:table-cell not working on an input element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element)

Comment: @Zigson interesting, it doesn't work on Firefox, but it makes sense, because `table-cell` acts like `<td>`, but `<input>` is a self close tag cannot contain any content inside.

Comment: It does not work on Firefox? Well, then extra <div> it is! :)

Comment: @Zigson no it doesn't work, of course wrap into <div> works, that was what I suggested in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full responsive solution.

HTML

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="input-flied-box">
            <form>
                <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Right Some thing" />
                <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/* RESPONSIVE CSS */
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
.input-flied-box{
    width: 100%;
}
.input-flied-box input{
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
}
.submit-button{
    top: inherit;
    right: inherit;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.container{
    width: 750px;
}
.input-flied-box{
    width: 600px;
}
.input-flied-box input{
    padding: 6px 101px 6px 12px;
}
.submit-button{
    top: 14px;
    right: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.container{
    width: 960px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
.container{
    width: 1170px;
}
}
/* RESPONSIVE CSS END */

*:after,
*:before{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container:after,
.container:before{
display: table;
content: " ";
clear: both;
}
.container{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.input-flied-box {
background-color: #666666;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
position: relative;
}
.input-flied-box input {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
height: 40px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
margin-top: 15px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.submit-button {
background-color: #fc3850;
border: medium none;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Arial;
line-height: 1;
padding: 13px 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bL3wgrv9/