# Dynamically setting component tagName

Tags: ember.js

From what I've seen this isn't exactly possible by default, but I was hoping that the new Glimmer engine might be able to improve this. I'm creating an inline edit component for within a table. By default, I want the component to be a td element, but selectively become an input element on interaction.

```
// components/inline-edit.js
tagName: 'td',
click: function() {
    this.set('tagName', 'input');
    this.rerender(); // prolly not necessary, but thought I'd give it a go
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Am I missing something? I'm using Ember 1.13.3, but do I need to opt into Glimmer for this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you render a input field hidden, then on click unhide it and focus? A `<td>` can't just become an `<input>` because `<input>` can't be the direct child of a `<tr>` nor would it make sense.

Comment: Because the input inside a table cell completely messes the layout of the table.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 Can't you style it? Replacing a cell with an input field wouldn't work, they aren't interchangeable.

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to style a input with display:table-cell than it would be to try to get an input inside of a td to fit properly and behave properly.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 https://jsfiddle.net/LkjboeL1/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=281357 it really isn't. It's quite easy to style the input element inside of a cell https://jsfiddle.net/beacj/2/

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I wasn't aware of that. Despite my bad premise, is it possible change the tagName and update the component?

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 I really can't imagine how that would work in the strictest sense since you're not just renaming the tag (tagName is read only in the HTML spec), you're changing the DOM from one element to another, it would unbind all the event handlers and whatever other references you hold and create a new element. 

Your only option I reckon is to pass in the `tagName` when initialising the component, based of some state that gets manipulated when you click the tag. This will cause the whole component to be replaced though.

Answer (score 1):

If an input element doesn't work for you how about an inline contenteditable:

```
// components/inline-edit.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  tagName: 'span',
  attributeBindings: ['contenteditable'],
  contenteditable: true,
  ...
});
```

And then use it inside the `<td>`:

```
{{#each}}
<tr>
  <td>{{inline-edit}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```