# Form in Column-Layout - unexpected behavior of Input and Labels

Tags: html, css, forms

**Edit:** Mistake has been explained. I will look into other ways to build multi-column forms with input-elements, hopefully in a 2016 fashion.

---

I'm new to HTML/JS/CSS. I did the w3school tutorials and am no stranger to so.com either - but while this is a great side, applying already posted solutions to my problem is rather tricky for a beginner.

**Task:** building simple websites for basic database access (think of VBA-Forms in Access, if no other means were available). IE11 will be used as Browser in a protected company environment.
Layout-wise there are to be several Rows with Labels in Col1, and one to X input-elemets in Col2 - ColX+1.

**Problem:** Oddly, labels and inputs behave different, even if assigned to the same class. 
"Appending" labels works in the expected way (new labels are "appended" to the right in new columns/new cells). 
"Appending" input-elements displayes them in the same row and column as the last one (see code for example. basically: the height of the label-cell in column1 now spans 2 cells in column2).

- I understand setting up forms in CSS tables is consideres bad practice.
- I am not yet sure if this also applies if i need a multi-row, multi-column (3+) layout. I figure non-tabular solutions get messy rather fast. The Examples i found on w3school and in stackoverflow-comments use at most two columns, one for the label and one for the input-element.
- To my undestanding, "display: table-columns" can only be used to format cells with a certain position in each row (like in a spreadsheet), and not to actually "add" a empty column that can be filled.

https://jsfiddle.net/9cjf1465/

The CSS: apart from some formatting, I create a class for forms (**table**), paragraphs (**row**), and individual labels/input (**cell**). Took out most of the formatting-stuff.

```
<style type="text/css">     
    div.mydiv {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    form.myform {
        display: table;
    }
    p.myrow {
        display: table-row;
    }
    /* class can used for both label and input? */
    .mycell {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    label {
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align:middle;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    input{
        vertical-align:middle;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px;
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
```

The Example-HTML, simplified: Note how Inputs and Labels behave differently as mentioned above - despite being assigned to the same class.

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <form class="myform" id="form1" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();getPnr()">
        <p class="myrow">
            <label class="mycell" for="pnr">Label 1</label>
            <input class="mycell" type="number" id="pnr" placeholder="Pnr" required >
            <input class="mycell myimp1" type="submit" id="btn1">
        </p>
        <p class="myrow">
            <label class="mycell" for="pnr">Label 2</label>
            <label class="mycell" for="pnr">Label 3</label>
            <input class="mycell" type="number" id="pnr" placeholder="Pnr" required >
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

I hope my question came across right and I kept myself short enough - already lookin forward to get some suggestions!

Cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know labels & inputs cannot be treated the same.

Labels are a container element ([more info](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_containers.asp)).

Elements which self close, such as inputs, images, etc are not containers and therefore cannot behave like a `<td>` or have `display:table-cell;`

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element) covers the same area, stating that use of `display:table-cell;` with an input would be experimental according to [W3.org](http://w3.org)

Comment: Hi Ben.Thanks for pointing that obvious error out! I somehow assumed it was a mere positioning-problem.
What confused me that Firefox's inspect-element view showed me different cells for different inputs, so I somehow assumed that the cell...container(?) itself was created correctly. The quoted  question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element) _italic_ obviously covered my problem.

Thanks for your Help! Also sorry for a redundant Question

Comment: @MartinDreher As an addition to Ben's answer, tables are _not_ evil per se. They just have been overused for layout purposes. If your form allows users to input tabular data you can still use tables and be within "2016 fashion". No need to use other tags and make them behave like a table.

Comment: If you do use a table for layout, make sure to add [`role="presentation"`](http://juicystudio.com/article/layout_tables_repair_techniques.php) so screen readers will not try to interpret it as a data table.

Comment: No problem Martin, best of luck. I also agree with Paul, there are times when a table would definitely be suitable so don't rule them out straight away.

Also in the interests of using Stackoverflow in the future if an answer has helped you with your problem could you please accept it and make it easier for other users to find.

Comment: @Paul: ok, so in a scenario where not only the layout, but the actual input data is tabular (let say, f.e. if the input would consist of several datarows) i could still use a form.
In which case, since <span>display: table-cell;</span> should not be used, i will ressort to the html <td> tags.
Also ty Steveax for that advice.

Comment: Exactly. `table` is still a valid HTML tag for a reason. ;)