# CSS table is combining cells into the same column in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a form that is styled with CSS as a table. However the two input elements are shown to be on top of each other and not side by side. How can I get them to be side by side?

As noted in the comments this might be browser related. I am running it on `IE 11.0.14393.0` on Windows 10.

```css
div,
a {
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", sans-serif
}

.FormContainer form {
 display: table;
}
.FormContainer form div {
 display: table-row;
}
.FormContainer form div label,
.FormContainer form div input {
 display: table-cell;
 margin: 5px 0px;
}
.FormContainer form div label {
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.FormContainer form div input[type=text] {
 min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
      <p><font size="6"><u><strong>Search Users</strong></u></font></p>
   <p>Search for...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="FormContainer">
      <form action="SearchNewestUsers.php" method="post">
        <div>
          <label for="UserCount">Newest users</label>
          <input type="text" name="UserCount" id="UserCount" placeholder="Enter number of users...">
          <input type="submit" name="SearchButton" id="SearchButton" value="Search">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

The snippet above produces the following output for me:

[image: Output]

Comment: your label and two inputs are already side by side...what's the problem?

Comment: I'm on IE11, that might be causing it...

Comment: Side note, don't use the `<font>` tag. It's obsolete. Use CSS.

Comment: have you tried adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> ?

Comment: @SergChernata Tried it but no luck

Comment: It looks like using table-cell on input is still experimental when you have multiple in a row like you do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625878/displaytable-cell-not-working-on-an-input-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the fault is with IE, and it doesn't seem to like the `display: table-cell` that you have. The solution I've found is to change to `inline-block` for the two inputs.

```css
div,
a {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", sans-serif
}
.FormContainer form {
  display: table;
}
.FormContainer form div {
  display: table-row;
}
.FormContainer form div label,
.FormContainer form div input {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.FormContainer form div input {
  display: inline-block!important;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}
.FormContainer form div label {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.FormContainer form div input[type=text] {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p><font size="6"><u><strong>Search Users</strong></u></font>
    </p>
    <p>Search for...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="FormContainer">
    <form action="SearchNewestUsers.php" method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="UserCount">Newest users</label>
        <input type="text" name="UserCount" id="UserCount" placeholder="Enter number of users...">
        <input type="submit" name="SearchButton" id="SearchButton" value="Search">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```